# Google API Authorization (Service Account) Error: HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: unauthorized_client: Unauthorized client or scope in request

Tags: python, youtube-api, google-oauth, google-api-client

I'm attempting to connect to the YouTube Analytics API using Python.  When I go to Google's Developer Console in the Credentials tab I click on the `Create credentials` drop-down menu and select `Help me choose`.  I click on the API I want to use (`YouTube Analytics API`), where I will be calling from (`Other non-UI (e.g. cron job, daemon)`), what data I will be accessing (`Application Data`), and then whether I'm using Google App Engine (`no`). I click on the button to see which credentials I need and it tells me `You alread have credentials that are suitable for this purpose`.

I have a `Service account` that I use to connect to the Google Search Console API to access data for multiple sites my company owns. Because we have multiple sites I use delegated credentials based on my email address.  This is the code I use to authenticate to the Search Console API:

```
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from apiclient.discovery import build

scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('keyfile.json', scopes=scopes)

delegated_credentials = credentials.create_delegated('<my-email>')
http_auth = delegated_credentials.authorize(Http())

webmasters_service = build('webmasters', 'v3', http=http_auth)
```

Now, I'm trying to use a similar approach with the YouTube Analytics API but I'm getting this error: `HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: unauthorized_client: Unauthorized client or scope in request.`.  Here's my code:

```
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from apiclient.discovery import build

START_DATE = "2016-09-01"
END_DATE = "2016-09-30"

scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('keyfile.json', scopes=scopes)

delegated_credentials = credentials.create_delegated('<my-email>')
http_auth = delegated_credentials.authorize(Http())

youtube_service = build('youtubeAnalytics', 'v1', http=http_auth)

analytics_query_response = youtube_service.reports().query(
    ids="channel==<my-youtube-channel-id>",
    metrics="views",
    start_date=START_DATE,
    end_date=END_DATE
).execute()
```

The `keyfile.json` is the same file (containing the Service account credentials) that I use to connect to the Search Console API. I even tried created a new Service account and used those credentials but I didn't have any luck. And yes, I've enabled the all of the YouTube APIs in the developer console.

**Do you have any idea why I'm getting the `HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: unauthorized_client: ...` error?**

edit: Previously I used an OAuth ID as opposed to a Service account, when I ran my script a browser tab was presented and I had to choose an account. I was presented with two options: one was my email, the other was the YouTube account that I was added as a manager. Do you think that I'm getting that error because I'm using my email address to generate credentials (and not the YouTube account)?

edit2: It appears that the YouTube account may not fall under the umbrella of our Google Apps domain. So, this may be why I can't authorize using my email address, even though I've been made a Manager of that YouTube account with that email address.

Comment: Have you enabled Access from the console from your IP

Comment: @UnknownDeveloper I'm not sure how exactly to do that but wouldn't I get the same error when connecting to the Google Search Console API as well? I don't have any issues with the Search Console API, just the YouTube Analytics API.  FYI I added some more information to my quesiton describing what happened when I used the OAuth approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found on this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/authentication) that you cannot use Service account with YouTube Analytics API.

It is stated here that:

> The service account flow supports server-to-server interactions that
>   do not access user information. However, the YouTube Analytics API
>   does not support this flow. Since there is no way to link a Service
>   Account to a YouTube account, attempts to authorize requests with this
>   flow will generate an error.

I also found it in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586153/youtube-analytics-google-service-account) answered by a Googler.

For more information, check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554106/using-the-youtube-analytics-api-with-a-cms-account).

Comment: Nice find, KENdi! I didn't notice that while reading over the Service Accounts section of the authorization documentation.  So, do I have to use OAuth to authenticate? Is that possible from a server running a cron job?